# Proper ways to initialize member variables with identical names as the parameters

Tags: c++11, syntax, conventions

I got a class that looks like this

```
class Rational{
    public:
        Rational(int p = 0, int q = 1) : p(p), q(q){};
    private:
        int p;
        int q;
};
```

My question is about the initialization syntax where member variables and constructor parameters has identical names.
I now know it is legal to do so, but my question is:
If I want do have "clean", easy to grasp code I wonder if I can do as one normally would do in java:

```
//Legal Java Code
this.q = q;
this.p = p;
//Is any of these legal C++ code (if so, which one)?
this.q(q);
this.p(p);
//or
this->q(q);
this->p(p);
```

Even though I haven't tested it, and I can test it, I still want to know the C++ conventions of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C++`, you have to say:

```
this -> q = q;
this -> p = p;
```

or equivalently

```
(*this).q = q;
(*this).p = p;
```

But I think the member initializer list syntax

```
Rational(int p = 0, int q = 1) : p(p), q(q){}
```

is cleaner (note the lack of a semicolon!) Why don't you like it?

Comment: Thank you @TonyK.
It is not that I don't like it, it's simply the fact that it might be confusing (even for me) when seeing two variables with identical names without explicit references. 
Since I am schooled with Java, I learnt that one **must** use explcit reference with "this"-keyword if member variable and local variable has identical names.

Comment: "Note the lack of a semicolon"
Does this apply, even if this is located in the header-file and I am doing the implementation in the cc-file?

Comment: @MahNas92: The closing brace of a function definition (which is what this is) never requires a semicolon. The semicolon is just an empty statement, which is ignored inside a class definition. For instance: `class C { ; ; ; } ;` Note that the semicolon after a class definition _is_ required!.